# Digital Communications block diagram question

Tags: ofdm, equalization, matched-filter

I am new to digital communications and trying to understand the basic underlying concepts of digital comm systems. So far , studying the course , I have some questions which if anyone can answer would be great.

In the transmit section, to represent the data (be whatever modulation we are using or No modulation), we have to represent bits/symbols (bits-no modulation, symbols-with modulation) in terms of pulse shaping function.   Am I right?

And mostly we use root raised cosine signal to represent the symbols in order to restrict the leakage and have square(approx) shaped spectrum

Comment: Hi Ash! Welcome here! Please don't ask 3 different questions in one question; ask three separate questions here! I know you're probably still question-rate limited as new user, but the idea really is that we post one answer to one question, so that we can discuss things en detail if we're experts.

Comment: your question A) for example could be summed up with "No, that's not really how it is, but…"; now, if I have two other unrelated questions to answer, I can't go into depth here. Is it OK if we simply remove B) and C) and let you ask these in two new questions?

Comment: It would also help if you could read all related answers on this site and point out what you still don't understand, as specific as possible. These questions have been asked several times before.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your replay and pointing out . I will update the question and start my question with part A .

Comment: So, let's discuss A) then :) so, "no modulation" doesn't exist. I'm not sure what you mean with this. Can you elaborate? Modulation refers to the change of some waveforms properties to contain information; without modulation, there's no information transport. But it seems you forget that the pulse shaper is actually usually just a system convolved with the impulse series representing the modulation symbols, so really not sure where you're taking this!

Comment: and: root raised cosine only has rectangular spectrum for $\beta=0$, and you can never use that in reality, since that's a sinc in time domain – and the reason you use a RRC is that you actually want to find a nice trade-off between "boundedness" in frequency and time domain. So, no, I'd say "we use RRC because it is approximately square" is the opposite of the conclusion I'd draw.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ... I agree with the fact of modulation.   As you mentioned that   " the pulse shaper is actually usually just a system convolved with the impulse series representing the modulation symbols ".... i.e the symbols from the modulation block are convolved with a pulse shaping filter at TX end ,, But do we always use pulse shaping even if channel is not guassian. because , if we use pulse shaping , I beleive , we need to use receive filter (matched filter ) at RX end to maximized the SNR at sampling instant

Comment: @MarcusMüller  . Thanks Marcus .. I am getting hold on the pulse shaping little bit now and also going through couple of other posts and GNU radio implmentation (guided tutorials) to check the outputs of using pulse shaping.

Comment: you cannot not do pulse shaping. That's physically impossible. No channel has infinite bandwidth.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but we can use non liner methods for pulse shaping like diodes & transistors & opamp(Schmitt trigger).